# Tomcat application access issues

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, geoserver

I have installed Easy Tomcat 7 using WHM and deployed an application geoserver. I am able to access that via IP but not via domain name, for example http://122.122.122.122:8080/geoserver. I would like to access the application using domain name like http://www.example.com/geoserver. I have taken the following steps:

1. I have gone through Cpanel documentation and they are saying I need to unpack war file and deploy under public_html folder, but it doesn't work for me.
2. Did tried to add Proxypass and Proxy Reversepass lines in httpd.conf under example.com domain's virtualhost entry.(**This is creating issue for me because i would like to run  PHP web application as well as geoserver simultaneously and they are communicating with each other using mod_jk**)

   ProxyPass /geoserver http://122.122.122.122/geoserver

   ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://122.122.122.122/geoserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your ProxyPass directives are just missing the port number for your tomcat. Try:

```
ProxyPass /geoserver http://122.122.122.122:8080/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://122.122.122.122:8080/geoserver
```